# Server side implementation of a chat application

Tags: java, php, sql-server, web-services, chat

Consider any chat application like gtalk, whatsapp. My question is related to how the server side implementation for these are done. The scenario is:
 Client A wants to talk to Client B, via a chat server S. When the communication is implemented, I assume there is NAT (Network Address Translation) server running on S, by which both parties identify themselves to S.
 After this point, S or whatever chat server runs on S, acts as the mediator between A and B. When A sends "Hi B, how are you?", this sentence must be going to S, and S would then send it to A.

My first question comes here: The communication between the client and server, is it encrypted? I know the data would be packetized according to TCP/IP communication stack, and that the data part of this packet would contain the actual text A sent. But this data part, is it secured by encryption? Meaning, if someone where to sniff the packets and extract the data, will they able to figure out what A send to B?
The reason I ask: If I were to make a chat application, how do I protect the privacy of my users from strangers or even myself (because what A has sent is visible to my server code, and I might as well write it to a file; who knows, Google could be doing this :P).

Now suppose B was offline, then S would have to delay sending the message to B until B comes online and asks for stored messages. Or at this point, consider an application like dropbox storing a file temporarily.

Second question: How does S store this message or file? How is the encryption done? In short, if I were to make such a product, how could I assure the users that their data is safe and private on our servers, that even I or my company cannot read it, even if we wanted to.

To summarize, how does a public domain website manage to keep it's users' data private and secure from strangers and itself?

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: "I assume there is NAT server running on S, by which both parties identify themselves to S" err, what? what does NAT mean here? Network Address Translation?

Comment: Yes. A and B both don't know each other's IP, so a mediator must talk to both , knowing their IPs. aka NAT. Thanks I'll edit the question to add the full-form

Comment: Do you want 1:1 or also many-to-many (group chats)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming 1:1 communication (in other words, Alice and Bob have a private communication) – group chats are tricky.

Have a look at [OTR](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/). Basically, you need **end-to-end encryption** and the chat client needs to be able to exchange keys with other users automatically and assist the user in determining whether he trusts a key (e.g. using the [Socialist Millionaire Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaire) that lets two users confirm each other's identity using questions about shared secrets. So, the server doesn't need any special code for this – it just forwards or stores the encrypted data without ever touching it. However, the client needs quite some code:

- The clients need to be able to **exchange public keys** automatically when two users talk to each other for the first time.
- The clients need to be able to **store other users' public keys** so that they notice when someone's key changes.
- The clients need to be able to assist the user at **confirming the other user's identity** (e.g. using the Socialist Millionaire protocol or by exchanging public key fingerprints over the telephone) and **store and permanently show information about this trust** (e.g. as a small "verified" icon next to the user's name).
- The clients need to be able to **encrypt/decrypt** and **sign/verify** messages from other peers using the keys that were exchanged on first contact.

Of course, to convince users that their clients really do what you say, you need to **disclose your source code** or at least **let a few independent parties review it**.

Comment: Thanks thejh! Looks like I may be able to use this.